# Can webpack-encore use the tsconfig.json for aliases?

Tags: typescript, symfony, webpack-encore

The typescript path configurations were not in sync with the webpack aliases in a symfony project that I was working on, because they were in two separate files. I found no obvious way to use the tsconfig.json paths as aliases with encore.

I tried installing the [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) and adding it with the addPlugin method.

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

Encore
.addPlugin(new TsconfigPathsPlugin());
```

And I got this when I ran webpack:

> tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin: No file system found on resolver. Please make sure you've placed the plugin in the correct part of the configuration. This plugin is a resolver plugin and should be placed in the resolve part of the Webpack configuration.